# Jaro-Winkler score calculation in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-dataset

We need to implement Jaro-Winkler distance calculation across string in Apache Spark **Dataset**. We are new to spark and after searching in web we are not able to find much. It would be great if you can guide us. We thought of using **flatMap** then realized it won’t help, then we tried to use couple of foreach loops but not able to figure how to go forward. As each of the string has to be compared against all. Like in the below dataset.

```
RowFactory.create(0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
RowFactory.create(1,"I wish Java could use case classes"),
RowFactory.create(2,"Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"));
```

Example jaro winkler score across all string found in the above dataframe.

> Distance score between label, 0,1 -> 0.56
>  Distance score between
>   label, 0,2 -> 0.77
>  Distance score between label, 0,3 -> 0.45
>   Distance score between label, 1,2 -> 0.77
>  Distance score between
>   label, 2,3 -> 0.79

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

    import info.debatty.java.stringsimilarity.JaroWinkler;

    public class JaroTestExample {
     public static void main( String[] args )
        {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil");
      JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs").setMaster("local[*]"));
      SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
      SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();
       JaroWinkler jw = new JaroWinkler();

            // substitution of s and t
            System.out.println(jw.similarity("My string", "My tsring"));

            // substitution of s and n
            System.out.println(jw.similarity("My string", "My ntrisg"));

            List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
        RowFactory.create(0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
        RowFactory.create(1,"I wish Java could use case classes"),
        RowFactory.create(2,"Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"));

            StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
      new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
        Metadata.empty()),
      new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
        Metadata.empty()) });

            Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);

            sentenceDataFrame.foreach();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross join in spark can be done using the below code 
Dataset2Object=Dataset1Object.crossJoin(Dataset2Object)
In Dataset2Object you get all combination of recordpair which is your need. In this case flatmap wont be helpfull.
Please remember to use version spark-sql_2.11 version 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

**Scala**

You can use the [spark-stringmetric](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-stringmetric) library as follows:

```scala
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.stringmetric.SimilarityFunctions

df.withColumn(
  "w1_w2_jaro_winkler",
  SimilarityFunctions.jaro_winkler(col("word1"), col("word2"))
)
```

**PySpark**

You can use the [ceja](https://github.com/MrPowers/ceja) library as follows:

```py
import ceja

df.withColumn("jaro_winkler_similarity", ceja.jaro_winkler_similarity(col("word1"), col("word2")))
```

Comment: It's be worth pointing out that these use UDF, so expect a slow performance as you would with any other python udf's

Comment: would it be better/ possible to use the Scala version in PySpark by importing it instead of the UDF in Ceja?

Comment: @Dee - good point out UDFs being slower.  You could write a Spark native function if you want faster performance.  See this blog post for instructions on how to write native functions: https://neapowers.com/apache-spark/native-functions-catalyst-expressions/. Using the Scala version & importing it in PySpark should give a similar result.  The only way to really make it faster is to write the native function.

Comment: I see, thought scala udf were a tad faster, I'm going to give it a go as my dataset is 3TB large. Perhaps a Java udf might be faster and easier to write than a native function to start with? Obrigado