# Jaro-Winkler score calculation in Apache Spark using java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

For an example

```
 List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
    RowFactory.create(0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
    RowFactory.create(1,"I wish Java could use case classes"),
    RowFactory.create(2,"Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"));
```

From this data I can create a vector by putting each word scores to each row.Each row shows different words : (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),(1,"I wish Java could use case classes"),(2,"Logistic,regression,models,are,neat")
Now i need to calculate a score to check the similarity between each and every pair of words and output should be a column vector.What is the best way to calculate this using spark(datasets) in java.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate, the same question was asked 3 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701733/jaro-winkler-score-calculation-in-apache-spark. Is it homework or are you both colleagues?

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment to me nevertheless it can't be flagged  as duplicate since the other question doesn't have an answer to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question either way for being broad.